# Viewpager call intent when user swipes from right to left

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewpager

I'm using `viewpager` for showing some introduction to the user, there are two screens, when both the screen are finished I have to pass the `intent`. Right now, I have implemented `viewpager` and passed the `intent`.

Here is what I have done so far:

Edited my source code:

IntroActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    final ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    OnPageChangeListener mListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selectedIndex = arg0;
            System.out.println("Selecte Page: " + selectedIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mPageEnd && arg0 == selectedIndex) {
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Okay");
                mPageEnd = false;// To avoid multiple calls.
            } else {
                mPageEnd = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (selectedIndex == adapter.getCount() - 1) {
                mPageEnd = true;
            }
        }
    };
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mListener);

}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] mImages = new int[] { R.drawable.libin1,
            R.drawable.libin2 };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = MainActivity.this;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Through these I'm able to implement the `viewpager`, but as you can see that I have called intent on `onTouchListener` when the user is on second screen.

My problem is that user can't see the first screen again if he wants to, because of the `touchListener()`, as soon as the user touches the screen the intent is called.

I have tried using `GestureListener` for `fling` action, but that is also not helping me.

How can I overcome this problem?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I advise you rethink your logic. The actions of going to another `Activity` and also being able to swipe to the previous page seems a bit contradictory, a notification presented to the user when he gets to the last page(inviting him to "close" this introduction) I think it's a better choice.

Anyway you could do what you want. Set a `OnPageChangeListener` on the `ViewPager` to listen for interactions:

```
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mCurrentState = state;
            // if we are at the second page and the user touched the
            // ViewPager post a Runnable with a decent time to schedule our
            // Intent
            if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mRun, INTERVAL);
                }
            }
        }
```

You'll need:

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private int mCurrentState = -1;
private static int INTERVAL = ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout();
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mRun = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // we got the Runnable to be executed. If we are on the second page
        // and the user let go of the ViewPager in our time frame then start
        // the Activity(also cancel the dozen Runnables that were posted)
        if (mCurrentState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
                && mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRun);// or always set it to run
            Intent i = new Intent(PagerTextTouch.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank You sooo much for your answer. It worked. You are magician dude.

Comment: Hello is it possible to know if user is trying to swipe the last page of viewpager in onpagechange listener methods

Comment: @prateek try to swipe the last page making the fading edge appear? If yes then you could do this with a combination between the `onPageScrollStateChanged()` and `onPageScrolled()`.

Comment: @Luksprog yup you are right I just did it using the same functions

Answer (score 0):

You will get postion of the view page by

```
private static class PageListener extends SimpleOnPageChangeListener{
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, "page selected " + position);
           currentPage = position;
          } 


}
```

Call the pageListner

`pageListener = new PageListener();
        ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);`

Now you can get the postion of the view